# CallKit - displaying outgoing call into recent call list

Tags: objective-c, ios10, callkit

I am implementing a VoIP application, there I handled remote party for incoming call like

```
- (NSUUID *)reportIncomingCallWithContactIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier name:(NSString *)name telNumber:(NSString *)telnum completion:(ADCallKitManagerCompletion)completion {
    NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID];

    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    //callUpdate.callerIdentifier = identifier;
    callUpdate.localizedCallerName = name;
    callUpdate.supportsHolding = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.supportsGrouping = NO;
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:telnum];
    [self.provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:callUUID update:callUpdate completion:completion];
    return callUUID;
}
```

As a result the incoming call is showing in recent phone call list. But when I make an outgoing call, the number is not showing in the recent call list(system's phone app). Current implementation:

```
- (NSUUID *)reportOutgoingCallContactIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier destination:(NSString *)name telNumber:(NSString *)telnum completion:(ADCallKitManagerCompletion)completion {
    NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID];
    //MARK::change in constructor, defined new handler
    CXHandle *handle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:telnum];
    CXStartCallAction *action = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID handle:handle];
    action.contactIdentifier = identifier;
    action.destination = name;

    [self.callController requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[action]] completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
    }];
    return callUUID;
}
```

I need to know how I update remote handler for any outgoing call so that this will show in the remote phone call list.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is your outgoing call actually starting successfully, and how are you ending the call? Calls are only added to the system's Recents list when the call ends, and an app uses either a `CXEndCallAction` or `-reportCallWithUUID:endedAtDate:reason:`

Comment: sorry for my late reply, yes i did that earlier but forgot to update the provider while call is being established. now it is showing in the recent list but not by name. for incoming call it is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For outgoing calls, updating the call using `reportCallWithUUID` right after performing `requestTransaction` does the job. but i'm not sure if it's the proper way as `reportCallWithUUID` is for updating any changes in an ongoing call.

```
- (NSUUID *)reportOutgoingCallContactIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier destination:(NSString *)name telNumber:(NSString *)telnum completion:(ADCallKitManagerCompletion)completion {
    NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID];
    //MARK::change in constructor, defined new handler
    CXHandle *handle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:telnum];
    CXStartCallAction *action = [[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:callUUID handle:handle];
    action.contactIdentifier = identifier;
    action.destination = name;
    [self.callController requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[action]] completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@",[error description]);
    }];

    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    [callUpdate setRemoteHandle:[[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber value:telnum]];
    callUpdate.localizedCallerName = @"NAME";
    [_provider reportCallWithUUID:callUUID updated:callUpdate];

    return callUUID;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me for some reason. But in most of the stackoverflow posts shows this as the solution. Maybe callkit has changed something now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CXStartCallAction and request a CXTransaction with this action in order for your reportOutgoingCall to work.

Comment: @makboney: and then did you implement `-provider:performStartCallAction:` in your provider delegate to actually start the outgoing call?

Comment: yes i have implemented that and outgoing call is working.